Deleted composite indexes in firestore but my queries are still working
I was cleaning up old composite indexes in my firestore when I realized that I deleted one composite index by mistake but my query continues to work perfectly. Initially it wouldn't work without that index.
Here is the query:
  const allCredits = await tx.get(
    db.collection(`users/${uid}/credits`)
    .where('expiresAt', '>', Date.now())
    .orderBy('expiresAt', 'desc'),
  );

Is there some caching or delay when deleting composite indexes in firebase?
I don't want to end up in a situation where this query will suddenly stop working because some index cache has been cleared. It's still working fine. Any thoughts?
Thanks!

The query you're showing doesn't require any composite indexes.  It only filters and orders on one field (expiresAt), so it can use the default index created for each individual field.  You only need composite indexes when there are multiple fields involved in filtering and ordering.
From the documentation, emphasis mine:

A composite index stores a sorted mapping of all the documents in a collection, based on an ordered list of fields to index.
Note: You can have at most one array field per composite index.
Cloud Firestore uses composite indexes to support queries not already supported by single-field indexes.

I can only assume that you are mistaken about this particular query requiring a composite index.

Thanks for clarification! That makes perfect sense now.
